# Adaptive Card rendered as image on FB shows "Title" text/element

Tags: botframework

I understand that adaptive cards are down-rendered as image on channels that does not support them. I just want to know how to either remove or set the "Title" element as shown on the fb channel:

[image]

The AdaptiveCard.Title element is deprecated and I did try setting that, it did not have any effect.

Here is my sample json:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "id": "Title",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "size": "Large",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "text": "See results on our website!"
    },
    {
        "type": "Image",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "url": "mylogo.png",
        "size": "Stretch"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "id": "Subtitle",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "size": "ExtraLarge",
        "text": "This channel does not allow us to display your results. Click the button to view it on our website.",
        "wrap": true
    }
],
"actions": [
  {
    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
    "id": "OpenUrl",
    "title": "Take me there!"
  }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, when the BotFramewrok renders the card into an image for Facebook Messenger it adds the title above the actions which is strange. The only way to get rid of it is to remove the action from the card, which defeats its purpose in this case. An alternative is to send a Facebook Button Template in the activity's channel data instead of the adaptive card when the user is on Facebook Messenger. For more details checkout the Facebook Documentation on [Button Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button/) and the code snippet below.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Bot Code - Node**

```
async onTurn(turnContext) {
    if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        if (turnContext.activity.channelId === 'facebook') {
            await turnContext.sendActivity({
                channelData: {
                      "attachment": {
                          "type": "template",
                          "payload": {
                              "template_type":"button",
                              "text":"This channel does not allow us to display your results. Click the button to view it on our website.",
                              "buttons":[{
                                  "type":"web_url",
                                  "url":"https://www.microsoft.com",
                                  "title":"Take me there!"
                              }]
                          }
                      }
                  }
              });
        } else {
            await turnContext.sendActivity({
                attachments: [this.createAdaptiveCard()], 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I find an alternative using HeroCard.

If you are developing it with C# there it goes the code:

```
// first of all check if it is Facebook channel
// note that Channels is from Microsoft.Bot.Connector, the old one is deprecated.
if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channels.Facebook)
{
      Activity replyToConversation = _flowService.ConvertMarkdownUrlToFacebookUrl(turnContext.Activity, response.Answer);
      await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(replyToConversation, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}


public Activity ConvertMarkdownUrlToFacebookUrl(Activity message, string queryResponse)
{
    var buttons = getButtons(queryResponse, out string result);

    Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply();
    replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    List<CardAction> actions = new List<CardAction>();

    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        actions.Add(new CardAction()
        {
            Title = button.Key, // text hyperlink
            Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
            Value = button.Value // url
        });
    }

    Attachment attachment = new HeroCard
    {
        Text = result, // your text
        Buttons = actions
    }.ToAttachment();
    replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    return replyToConversation;
}
```

You'll obtain something like this:

[image: example of how it looks in Facebook]

(sorry I had to delete the text)

Maybe it's not perfect (my first time with cards and attachments) but I hope that this will help someone